# ASRock x58 Extreme Motherboard Memory Layout

Tags: memory, motherboard, triple-channel

I am using the ASRock x58 Extreme Motherboard.

I currently have installed 8GB of DDR3 (4 x 2GB) memory that is compatible with the MB.

I recently received an additional 8 GB of DDR3 (2 x 4GB) RAM from the same manufacturer and model / speed (ie. identical except for size).

According to the manual, I should install 'identical' DIMMs in all six slots to enable triple channel configuration. It also says that if I don't install identical DIMMs that it will map to the lower size for triple channel and use the rest for single channel operation.

What is the best way to install my DIMMs on this motherboard, and the implications of installing this way?

Here is the manual:
http://66.226.78.22/downloadsite/Manual/X58%20Extreme.pdf

Since there has been some confusion on what I'm asking, let me clarify.
I have 6 DIMMs; 2 4GB and 4 2GB.

I'm trying to decide if it would be better to

1. 3 2GB DIMMs in triple and 2 4GB DIMMs in double

OR

2. 3 2GB DIMMs in triple and 2 4GB DIMMs w/ the 2GB DIMM in the other channel
   (which would (if I understand correctly) effectively be 2GB in triple and 2 2GB in single)

OR

3. Some other objectively better configuration

I'm interested in not only the best configuration, but WHY it is better.

Comment: Page 12, from the document you linked, has your answer.

Comment: @Ramhound How so? Page 12 is the MoBo layout. Did you mean page 18 (which has the memory slot layout?) If so, this does not give me an answer, it only states that I should fill the slots; not if it would be better for me to put a 4GB DIMM on each channel or to put them both on the same channel. Or the possibility of running without one of my 2GB DIMMs, or any number of other (possibly equivalent) configurations.

Answer (score 0):

```
DDR3_A1, DDR3_B1, DDR3_A2, DDR3_B2
4 GB,    4 GB,    2 GB,    2GB.
```

This would be the recommended configuration according to the manual.

Comment: You seem to be recommending that I leave out 4GB (2 x 2GB) and not utilize my C slots. This would not allow me to Triple Channel (which is fine), but I don't see any advantage to using your configuration above, since it seems my MoBo doesn't support Dual Channel. Can you elaborate on why this would be the preferred configuration?

Comment: Addendum/correction, it seems the MoBo does support Dual channel.

Answer (score 0):

to run triple channel u need the same size memory in each of the X1 or X2 slots
so if u put 3x 2G modules in A1, B1, C1 those will run triple channel.
the rest will run single channel in slots A2, B2, C2